# No subject alternative names during FTP SSL Connection with maven

Tags: java, maven, ssl, ftps, apache-commons-net

I am using maven to upload files to a FTP server. Without notice they seem to have adjusted their security to SSL. In my maven script i made a change to the  url but now i am getting a CertificationException and i dont how to solve this issue.

I changed ftp://ftp01.company.nl to  ftps://ftp01.company.nl because i was getting the following error (and it seems correct to do so)

```
 Reply received: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
 Command sent: USER username
 Reply received: 534 Policy requires SSL.
 ftp://ftp01.company.nl - Session: Connection refused
```

However with ftps://ftp01.company.nl i am getting a new error:

```
 Reply received: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
 Command sent: AUTH TLS
 Reply received: 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
 Session error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
 java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching 
 IP address 54.111.424.3 found
 ftps://ftp01.company.nl- Session: Connection refused

 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload (upload-philips-site) on project nl.esi.comma.types: Unable to create a Wagon instance for ftps://ftp01.company.nl: Could not connect to server. java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 54.111.424.3 found -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload (upload-philips-site) on project nl.esi.comma.types: Unable to create a Wagon instance for ftps://134.221.44.5:21
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
       Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to create a Wagon instance for ftps://ftp01.company.nl
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractWagonMojo.createWagon(AbstractWagonMojo.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractSingleWagonMojo.execute(AbstractSingleWagonMojo.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication.AuthenticationException: Could not connect to server.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ftp.FtpWagon.openConnectionInternal(FtpWagon.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection(AbstractWagon.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect(AbstractWagon.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.shared.WagonUtils.createWagon(WagonUtils.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.wagon.AbstractWagonMojo.createWagon(AbstractWagonMojo.java:82)
    ... 23 more
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 134.221.44.5 found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:226)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ftp.FtpWagon.openConnectionInternal(FtpWagon.java:128)
    ... 28 more
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 54.111.424.3 found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:168)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1019)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:986)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 40 more
```

openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -connect ftp01.company.nl:990

```
    CONNECTED(000001A4)
    depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
    verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=NL/ST=Zuid-Holland/L=Den Haag/OU=Information Services/O=COMPANY/CN=ftp01.company.nl
       i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIGTjCCBTagAwIBAgIMToqSFenheZ4SdipkMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGYxCzAJ
    BgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9iYWxTaWduIG52LXNhMTwwOgYDVQQDEzNH
    bG9iYWxTaWduIE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIENBIC0gU0hBMjU2IC0g
    RzIwHhcNMTgwMzE5MTU1MzI0WhcNMTkwMzIwMTU1MzI0WjB7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJO
    TDEVMBMGA1UECAwMWnVpZC1Ib2xsYW5kMREwDwYDVQQHDAhEZW4gSGFhZzEdMBsG
    A1UECwwUSW5mb3JtYXRpb24gU2VydmljZXMxDDAKBgNVBAoMA1ROTzEVMBMGA1UE
    AwwMZnRwMDEudG5vLm5sMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
    zSs0FmfHVtFzD3cEurv+l97RrSFPtBgzdK00dRaXomXaOFbkhW7BaI9yinkSdx7O
    yFrxgfx9RvF4bfAtVD19wZkQo3KR4Qlmt8gRslGUOv4A/XWOXBrMxdaZM1omSPsd
    lmfdzSZiCUelOxwwiWaR/EJTm7XUVa9zWatHdPQu9kNziDVJAHpSl3VeS7Q8QD65
    nzseANKdNw7quyzMaiGNYKvzIfbExZ9OLVlpyC8CDur8ke75yIWNFJv0ybDKIbku
    0AMu1PZfgvJ5ig3DKDyRw34lMds23+PIM5fDBWpjqHb441nG6rQ18GYBylFm9ibO
    il20xxuNN8ayqO70awYgcQIDAQABo4IC5TCCAuEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMIGg
    BggrBgEFBQcBAQSBkzCBkDBNBggrBgEFBQcwAoZBaHR0cDovL3NlY3VyZS5nbG9i
    YWxzaWduLmNvbS9jYWNlcnQvZ3Nvcmdhbml6YXRpb252YWxzaGEyZzJyMS5jcnQw
    PwYIKwYBBQUHMAGGM2h0dHA6Ly9vY3NwMi5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNvbS9nc29yZ2Fu
    aXphdGlvbnZhbHNoYTJnMjBWBgNVHSAETzBNMEEGCSsGAQQBoDIBFDA0MDIGCCsG
    AQUFBwIBFiZodHRwczovL3d3dy5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNvbS9yZXBvc2l0b3J5LzAI
    BgZngQwBAgIwCQYDVR0TBAIwADBJBgNVHR8EQjBAMD6gPKA6hjhodHRwOi8vY3Js
    Lmdsb2JhbHNpZ24uY29tL2dzL2dzb3JnYW5pemF0aW9udmFsc2hhMmcyLmNybDAX
    BgNVHREEEDAOggxmdHAwMS50bm8ubmwwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsG
    AQUFBwMCMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQrNLnI+fR/fg9+a9yu5b0mywKe+jAfBgNVHSMEGDAW
    gBSW3mHxvRwWKVMcwMx9O4MAQOYafDCCAQQGCisGAQQB1nkCBAIEgfUEgfIA8AB1
    AG9Tdqwx8DEZ2JkApFEV/3cVHBHZAsEAKQaNsgiaN9kTAAABYj73JEkAAAQDAEYw
    RAIgY69omnBaw9JQexXM6kUcbBMXtw3UYDbUepwNGqHzFlgCIGqK06EYkh9jnSg0
    WsZEiXXO4f28EBlNJcrpkQCTEhRZAHcApLkJkLQYWBSHuxOizGdwCjw1mAT5G9+4
    43fNDsgN3BAAAAFiPvclegAABAMASDBGAiEAoDPScqwsg6fPZzgmLhyocgYNu7Em
    XAIqmGgQwLBSOEMCIQD2V8+AfnAbRbW0GkFuzlWxj/fseKMMOLs3aEVhqKB9gDAN
    BgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEACcwFOiaqJFaN2gl2hGmoafD2+NOuobgA1nj1ow1X
    dWTxNIJhVDCloTZkoJ2UrHn/I5kT+TF7CA95k4G7lCzVJsgByn1SWY+ENYZ0vBsB
    6EmELTXqZTgpDLRnOQtm8kEM4UJGGResgbqMMknfOB6kuRaPCjViKM4MROsMZeUU
    952o9h4IQQIejDN58FekT9FBbijCSeWfAJ72Oksrqvk6NDlUuYROp0PRTMYBDCf9
    ZUMO0EaoBHtn2A+iK/ZVLz5MmjqF1ubCukSKF8GjeDaptgPEjRQpcEVXjm5fzyMB
    +ik/Z1orH/ukIQPU8Jy5eJZPb7rlaURw5TpgF58s4/+ckQ==
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
     1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
       i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIEaTCCA1GgAwIBAgILBAAAAAABRE7wQkcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwVzELMAkG
    A1UEBhMCQkUxGTAXBgNVBAoTEEdsb2JhbFNpZ24gbnYtc2ExEDAOBgNVBAsTB1Jv
    b3QgQ0ExGzAZBgNVBAMTEkdsb2JhbFNpZ24gUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0xNDAyMjAxMDAw
    MDBaFw0yNDAyMjAxMDAwMDBaMGYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9i
    YWxTaWduIG52LXNhMTwwOgYDVQQDEzNHbG9iYWxTaWduIE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiBW
    YWxpZGF0aW9uIENBIC0gU0hBMjU2IC0gRzIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IB
    DwAwggEKAoIBAQDHDmw/I5N/zHClnSDDDlM/fsBOwphJykfVI+8DNIV0yKMCLkZc
    C33JiJ1Pi/D4nGyMVTXbv/Kz6vvjVudKRtkTIso21ZvBqOOWQ5PyDLzm+ebomchj
    SHh/VzZpGhkdWtHUfcKc1H/hgBKueuqI6lfYygoKOhJJomIZeg0k9zfrtHOSewUj
    mxK1zusp36QUArkBpdSmnENkiN74fv7j9R7l/tyjqORmMdlMJekYuYlZCa7pnRxt
    Nw9KHjUgKOKv1CGLAcRFrW4rY6uSa2EKTSDtc7p8zv4WtdufgPDWi2zZCHlKT3hl
    2pK8vjX5s8T5J4BO/5ZS5gIg4Qdz6V0rvbLxAgMBAAGjggElMIIBITAOBgNVHQ8B
    Af8EBAMCAQYwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUlt5h8b0cFilT
    HMDMfTuDAEDmGnwwRwYDVR0gBEAwPjA8BgRVHSAAMDQwMgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWJmh0
    dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdsb2JhbHNpZ24uY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvMDMGA1UdHwQsMCow
    KKAmoCSGImh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5uZXQvcm9vdC5jcmwwPQYIKwYB
    BQUHAQEEMTAvMC0GCCsGAQUFBzABhiFodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNv
    bS9yb290cjEwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUYHtmGkUNl8qJUC99BM00qP/8/UswDQYJKoZI
    hvcNAQELBQADggEBAEYq7l69rgFgNzERhnF0tkZJyBAW/i9iIxerH4f4gu3K3w4s
    32R1juUYcqeMOovJrKV3UPfvnqTgoI8UV6MqX+x+bRDmuo2wCId2Dkyy2VG7EQLy
    XN0cvfNVlg/UBsD84iOKJHDTu/B5GqdhcIOKrwbFINihY9Bsrk8y1658GEV1BSl3
    30JAZGSGvip2CTFvHST0mdCF/vIhCPnG9vHQWe3WVjwIKANnuvD58ZAWR65n5ryA
    SOlCdjSXVWkkDoPWoC209fN5ikkodBpBocLTJIg1MGCUF7ThBCIxPTsvFwayuJ2G
    K1pp74P1S8SqtCr4fKGxhZSM9AyHDPSsQPhZSZg=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    ---
    Server certificate
    subject=/C=NL/ST=Zuid-Holland/L=Den Haag/OU=Information Services/O=COMPANY/CN=ftp01.company.nl
    issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    Peer signing digest: SHA1
    Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 3282 bytes and written 342 bytes
    Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    ---
    New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    Server public key is 2048 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    No ALPN negotiated
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.2
        Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
        Session-ID: 1E21000059E17A809E4D608A47B6E9A2F0ABF48751C43771ACDE452BD1245976
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Master-Key: CF98458314DFC1EC86699F9E0D881B69A5651BC5AA31D1879D5ED35E89C5EC15259EE15C58DDE016D5F06596F4131CE2
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        Start Time: 1522331987
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
        Extended master secret: yes
    ---
    220 Microsoft FTP Service
    read:errno=0
```

Maven:

```
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </extension>
        ...
        ...   
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>upload-site</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>upload</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <fromDir>../project/target/repository</fromDir>
                        <includes>**</includes>
                        <toDir>/location/</toDir>
                        <url>ftps://ftp01.company.nl</url>
                        <serverId>project-company-site</serverId>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

After some research i believe the problem is that this maven/java solution looks for the IP in the certificate but this only contains the domain name, ftp01.comany.nl. How can i solve this issue? Or should the owner of the FTP return a better certificate.

**UPDATE 8u162:**

Output with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:

```
        Reply received: 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Command sent: AUTH TLS

Reply received: 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1505632364 bytes = { 242, 165, 204, 139, 161, 64, 186, 156, 83, 226, 52, 246, 47, 120, 200, 177, 14, 56, 75, 178, 233, 35, 193, 96, 245, 134, 132, 191 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3186
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1505632315 bytes = { 15, 31, 179, 34, 223, 202, 91, 45, 105, 137, 88, 242, 124, 143, 54, 152, 143, 62, 144, 193, 98, 61, 21, 188, 123, 97, 161, 162 }
Session ID:  {130, 1, 0, 0, 232, 235, 43, 27, 234, 233, 4, 148, 139, 8, 158, 147, 48, 16, 98, 200, 200, 115, 114, 185, 28, 21, 145, 79, 237, 147, 59, 246}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ftp01.company.nl, O=company, OU=Information Services, L=Den Haag, ST=Zuid-Holland, C=NL
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 25900156941586816520413887033350249400393624576347862043983159913455812253648708590570114642493898690741793139995814318263915068692576230769170799471589433261405072688634547243472406197930596801161287736220338406394900314757646067417670876456965056307622794328274717528814007924177382904986265419059902363250704562989321715192902962892892868249292162997393582399055970676023717823596154154205859665046489196487884354445817517012498822165974731700475504207566052583002530592503560144376539770967391053009210483477086614983678518980796021381371942861266049670709421281434758586007062786241498555010556257989170248949873
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Mar 19 16:53:24 CET 2018,
               To: Wed Mar 20 16:53:24 CET 2019]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  SerialNumber: [    4e8a9215 e9e1799e 12762a64]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 81 F5 04 81 F2 00 F0   00 75 00 6F 53 76 AC 31  .........u.oSv.1
0010: F0 31 19 D8 99 00 A4 51   15 FF 77 15 1C 11 D9 02  .1.....Q..w.....
0020: C1 00 29 06 8D B2 08 9A   37 D9 13 00 00 01 62 3E  ..).....7.....b>
0030: F7 24 49 00 00 04 03 00   46 30 44 02 20 63 AF 68  .$I.....F0D. c.h
0040: 9A 70 5A C3 D2 50 7B 15   CC EA 45 1C 6C 13 17 B7  .pZ..P....E.l...
0050: 0D D4 60 36 D4 7A 9C 0D   1A A1 F3 16 58 02 20 6A  ..`6.z......X. j
0060: 8A D3 A1 18 92 1F 63 9D   28 34 5A C6 44 89 75 CE  ......c.(4Z.D.u.
0070: E1 FD BC 10 19 4D 25 CA   E9 91 00 93 12 14 59 00  .....M%.......Y.
0080: 77 00 A4 B9 09 90 B4 18   58 14 87 BB 13 A2 CC 67  w.......X......g
0090: 70 0A 3C 35 98 04 F9 1B   DF B8 E3 77 CD 0E C8 0D  p.<5.......w....
00A0: DC 10 00 00 01 62 3E F7   25 7A 00 00 04 03 00 48  .....b>.%z.....H
00B0: 30 46 02 21 00 A0 33 D2   72 AC 2C 83 A7 CF 67 38  0F.!..3.r.,...g8
00C0: 26 2E 1C A8 72 06 0D BB   B1 26 5C 02 2A 98 68 10  &...r....&\.*.h.
00D0: C0 B0 52 38 43 02 21 00   F6 57 CF 80 7E 70 1B 45  ..R8C.!..W...p.E
00E0: B5 B4 1A 41 6E CE 55 B1   8F F7 EC 78 A3 0C 38 BB  ...An.U....x..8.
00F0: 37 68 45 61 A8 A0 7D 80                            7hEa....


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsorganizationvalsha2g2r1.crt
,
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsorganizationvalsha2g2
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 96 DE 61 F1 BD 1C 16 29   53 1C C0 CC 7D 3B 83 00  ..a....)S....;..
0010: 40 E6 1A 7C                                        @...
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsorganizationvalsha2g2.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.1.20]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 26 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 67 6C  .&https://www.gl
0010: 6F 62 61 6C 73 69 67 6E   2E 63 6F 6D 2F 72 65 70  obalsign.com/rep
0020: 6F 73 69 74 6F 72 79 2F                            ository/

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.2]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ftp01.company.nl
]

[10]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 2B 34 B9 C8 F9 F4 7F 7E   0F 7E 6B DC AE E5 BD 26  +4........k....&
0010: CB 02 9E FA                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 09 CC 05 3A 26 AA 24 56   8D DA 09 76 84 69 A8 69  ...:&.$V...v.i.i
0010: F0 F6 F8 D3 AE A1 B8 00   D6 78 F5 A3 0D 57 75 64  .........x...Wud
0020: F1 34 82 61 54 30 A5 A1   36 64 A0 9D 94 AC 79 FF  .4.aT0..6d....y.
0030: 23 99 13 F9 31 7B 08 0F   79 93 81 BB 94 2C D5 26  #...1...y....,.&
0040: C8 01 CA 7D 52 59 8F 84   35 86 74 BC 1B 01 E8 49  ....RY..5.t....I
0050: 84 2D 35 EA 65 38 29 0C   B4 67 39 0B 66 F2 41 0C  .-5.e8)..g9.f.A.
0060: E1 42 46 19 17 AC 81 BA   8C 32 49 DF 38 1E A4 B9  .BF......2I.8...
0070: 16 8F 0A 35 62 28 CE 0C   44 EB 0C 65 E5 14 F7 9D  ...5b(..D..e....
0080: A8 F6 1E 08 41 02 1E 8C   33 79 F0 57 A4 4F D1 41  ....A...3y.W.O.A
0090: 6E 28 C2 49 E5 9F 00 9E   F6 3A 4B 2B AA F9 3A 34  n(.I.....:K+..:4
00A0: 39 54 B9 84 4E A7 43 D1   4C C6 01 0C 27 FD 65 43  9T..N.C.L...'.eC
00B0: 0E D0 46 A8 04 7B 67 D8   0F A2 2B F6 55 2F 3E 4C  ..F...g...+.U/>L
00C0: 9A 3A 85 D6 E6 C2 BA 44   8A 17 C1 A3 78 36 A9 B6  .:.....D....x6..
00D0: 03 C4 8D 14 29 70 45 57   8E 6E 5F CF 23 01 FA 29  ....)pEW.n_.#..)
00E0: 3F 67 5A 2B 1F FB A4 21   03 D4 F0 9C B9 78 96 4F  ?gZ+...!.....x.O
00F0: 6F BA E5 69 44 70 E5 3A   60 17 9F 2C E3 FF 9C 91  o..iDp.:`..,....

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 25128534854946729689874225426937401505000881204706872255627098498474475295641403147428295231173090028665490451781016201369028386293751105000607980749389164896950295472415799544200821826598281622670047877476444380361331431510582219613042406283138772574077178828514459453291208108705648245160199047848714530696719439161049181407350831720090579906068909416515809757315311589912849752912945272005465192109502201681085714022553142452002065884519487869175097916258424515352321964381962068601310395827347949688386139631202235593096601000028863153912492627308071474449386570163993017908691119484112907211941619220357798802161
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Feb 20 11:00:00 CET 2014,
               To: Tue Feb 20 11:00:00 CET 2024]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  SerialNumber: [    04000000 0001444e f04247]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.globalsign.com/rootr1
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 60 7B 66 1A 45 0D 97 CA   89 50 2F 7D 04 CD 34 A8  `.f.E....P/...4.
0010: FF FC FD 4B                                        ...K
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.net/root.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.5.29.32.0]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 26 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 67 6C  .&https://www.gl
0010: 6F 62 61 6C 73 69 67 6E   2E 63 6F 6D 2F 72 65 70  obalsign.com/rep
0020: 6F 73 69 74 6F 72 79 2F                            ository/

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 96 DE 61 F1 BD 1C 16 29   53 1C C0 CC 7D 3B 83 00  ..a....)S....;..
0010: 40 E6 1A 7C                                        @...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 46 2A EE 5E BD AE 01 60   37 31 11 86 71 74 B6 46  F*.^...`71..qt.F
0010: 49 C8 10 16 FE 2F 62 23   17 AB 1F 87 F8 82 ED CA  I..../b#........
0020: DF 0E 2C DF 64 75 8E E5   18 72 A7 8C 3A 8B C9 AC  ..,.du...r..:...
0030: A5 77 50 F7 EF 9E A4 E0   A0 8F 14 57 A3 2A 5F EC  .wP........W.*_.
0040: 7E 6D 10 E6 BA 8D B0 08   87 76 0E 4C B2 D9 51 BB  .m.......v.L..Q.
0050: 11 02 F2 5C DD 1C BD F3   55 96 0F D4 06 C0 FC E2  ...\....U.......
0060: 23 8A 24 70 D3 BB F0 79   1A A7 61 70 83 8A AF 06  #.$p...y..ap....
0070: C5 20 D8 A1 63 D0 6C AE   4F 32 D7 AE 7C 18 45 75  . ..c.l.O2....Eu
0080: 05 29 77 DF 42 40 64 64   86 BE 2A 76 09 31 6F 1D  .)w.B@dd..*v.1o.
0090: 24 F4 99 D0 85 FE F2 21   08 F9 C6 F6 F1 D0 59 ED  $......!......Y.
00A0: D6 56 3C 08 28 03 67 BA   F0 F9 F1 90 16 47 AE 67  .V<.(.g......G.g
00B0: E6 BC 80 48 E9 42 76 34   97 55 69 24 0E 83 D6 A0  ...H.Bv4.Ui$....
00C0: 2D B4 F5 F3 79 8A 49 28   74 1A 41 A1 C2 D3 24 88  -...y.I(t.A...$.
00D0: 35 30 60 94 17 B4 E1 04   22 31 3D 3B 2F 17 06 B2  50`....."1=;/...
00E0: B8 9D 86 2B 5A 69 EF 83   F5 4B C4 AA B4 2A F8 7C  ...+Zi...K...*..
00F0: A1 B1 85 94 8C F4 0C 87   0C F4 AC 40 F8 59 49 98  ...........@.YI.

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 123.123.12.1 found
 Session error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 123.123.12.1 found
ftps://ftp01.company.nl - Session: Connection refused
```

Comment: Old java versions don't send SNI extension, check you are using 8u131 minimum. A debugging tip : use -Djavax.net.debug=ssl and we will see if the extension is just not sent, or if it is the IP address of the Exception instead of the domain name.

Comment: I am using version 8u144. I added -Djavax.net.debug=ssl output to the post. I dont have much experience on reading this output but it does seem to use the DNSName: ftp01.company.nl?

Comment: We see that the Extension for the SNI is absent, such as with bugged JVMs. Is it possible to upgrade it ? Otherwise, it will be difficult to find the guilty part (Maven ? Apache commons ?)

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like the used FTP library does not use the hostname but the IP address to connect to the server. Of course in such a  case the DNS names in the certificate do not match as the IP address is not included in the certificate. Therefore I would assume that this is a bug of wagon-ftp.

Comment: I upgraded to 8u162. The new log output is added to the post it seems to be the same, no Extension for the SNI.

Comment: I'm posting an answer since it couldn't fit in a comment. We'll edit this answer when we find the solution (if we do).

Comment: (@EugèneAdell) if the application code (wagon?) specifies host by IP address, as Robert said and I think the exception message confirms, even correct versions of JSSE do not send SNI, because the SNI spec only permits domain names not IP addresses -- which I assume you mangled for posting because no IP4 addr can contain an octet 424. (In contrast _SAN in the cert_ does support IP addresses, although a given CA might or might not issue certs using them.) And remember `openssl s_client` without `-servername` never sends SNI.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks once more. I tried to find where in the code of FTPSClient there is anything related to DNS resolution. And this line 266 could be guilty.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem. To me it seems it's either in Wagon or Apache Commons. Wagon converts ftp01.company.nl to an IP adress which can not be found as subject alternative name. Or its the suspicious line 266 of FTPSClient

Answer (score 0):

The SNI should be set by default with the Java version you were using even before the upgrade. We don't see any explicit call to [the only method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setSSLParameters-javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters-) known to me to force the SNI value, in the *Apache Commons FTPSClient*.

Only one line gives me some trouble as I don't know exactly what it's doing. It's line 266.

If we are facing a reverse DNS issue because FTPSClient is bugged, you could try adding an entry in your hosts file

```
46.235.43.64 ftp01.company.nl
```

It seems we are not resolving the same IP (123.123.12.1 in your second trace), adapt your hosts accordingly.

```
$ grep 'void sslNegotiation' -A 30 -n commons-net/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.java
261:    protected void sslNegotiation() throws IOException {
262-        plainSocket = _socket_;
263-        initSslContext();
264-
265-        SSLSocketFactory ssf = context.getSocketFactory();
266-        String host = (_hostname_ != null) ? _hostname_ : getRemoteAddress().getHostAddress();
267-        int port = _socket_.getPort();
268-        SSLSocket socket =
269-            (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(_socket_, host, port, false);
270-        socket.setEnableSessionCreation(isCreation);
271-        socket.setUseClientMode(isClientMode);
272-
273-        // client mode
274-        if (isClientMode) {
275-            if (tlsEndpointChecking) {
276-                SSLSocketUtils.enableEndpointNameVerification(socket);
277-            }
278-        } else { // server mode
279-            socket.setNeedClientAuth(isNeedClientAuth);
280-            socket.setWantClientAuth(isWantClientAuth);
281-        }
282-
283-        if (protocols != null) {
284-            socket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
285-        }
286-        if (suites != null) {
287-            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
288-        }
289-        socket.startHandshake();
290-
291-        // TODO the following setup appears to duplicate that in the super class methods
```

> Without notice they seem to have adjusted their security to SSL.

It is not recommended to disable the access to clients coming without the SNI. There should be a default Virtual Host, whenever possible, and if there is only one Virtual Host then the SNI is not useful and should not be checked.